Create multiple views of the same stream or other ways to achieve the same effect in C#
I am now developing a cache system for my project which the cached contents are all stored in the same file(just like how runtime objects of a programming language get stored in the memory), the file is then mmaped so I can read and write it as if I'm working with a memory cache, now, what I can obtain is the byte array of a portion of that mmaped file, and I want to represent it using a stream, the best way is of course a stream that directly backed by the contents on the disk without actual copying the buffer , but I don't think there's a way to do it (or prove me wrong?). So a secondary way is to somehow "share" that portion in the form of a stream (stream is obligatory here, the pointer won't work, since it's about to be used with some 3rd party APIs which accept only streams, however, I don't want to use a MemoryStream given than it copy's the byte buffer entirely, contradicting the purpose of a cache, what I want is that I can have only one stream, but multiple views of it, such that consuming these views does not actually copies the buffer, so that I can provide these views to those APIs. However, it seemed to me that it's impossible to make such views  subclasses of stream, since the stream relies on 'Read' and 'Write' functions which always require copying, so here's my problems: is there a way to do such thing, no matter how trick it in C#?

I'm not sure if the mmaped file and the buffer you mentioned are the same thing as what we usually refer to, since as far as I know there is a method called MemoryMappedFile.CreateViewStream in C#, and CPU cannot directly access the disk, so buffers are always needed.

First, try to make your question fun readable, many will tldr.

The memorystream will not create a copy, when the buffer is passed as argument to the constructor.

You should be able to either use an inbuilt MMF stream, or write your own stream type that wraps the MMF pointer - maybe 20 minutes work?

But, I would avoid trashing the disk by using the filesystem.
Instead of writing buffers to a file (and share it to consumers), you can use the Channel<T> provider/consumer classes.
Here's an example: (this example doesn't take slow consumers into account, so you need to figure something out there)
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a channel for communication between provider and consumers
        var channel = Channel.CreateUnbounded<int>();

        // Start the provider
        var providerTask = Provider(channel.Writer);

        // Start multiple consumers
        var consumerTasks = new List<Task>
        {
            Consumer(channel.Reader, "Consumer 1"),
            Consumer(channel.Reader, "Consumer 2"),
            Consumer(channel.Reader, "Consumer 3")
        };

        // Wait for the provider to finish
        await providerTask;

        // Complete the channel so consumers know no more data is coming
        channel.Writer.Complete();

        // Wait for all consumers to finish
        await Task.WhenAll(consumerTasks);

        Console.WriteLine("All tasks completed.");
    }

    static async Task Provider(ChannelWriter<int> writer)
    {
        // Produce 10 items
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Provider: Producing item {i}");
            await writer.WriteAsync(i);
            await Task.Delay(500); // Simulate a delay in producing items
        }
    }

    static async Task Consumer(ChannelReader<int> reader, string consumerName)
    {
        // Process items until the channel is closed and all items are read
        await foreach (var item in reader.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{consumerName}: Processing item {item}");
            await Task.Delay(1000); // Simulate processing time
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"{consumerName}: No more items to process.");
    }
}

And ofcourse, instead of an int, you should use buffers and stream them to the socket. This way the buffer isn't copied for all consumers.
